# How to interact with buzz.sound function outside function scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function audio(path2audio){
    var mySound = new buzz.sound ( path2audio, {
        formats: ["mp3"],
        preload: false,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: false,
        volume: 70,
    });
    mySound.play();
}

http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/documentation/sound/


Well, I need to make a trigger called outside this function in order to stop the audio file to stop playing. My difficulty is that whenever I call the method outside the function, it shows an error: "main.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined".

mySound.bind('playing', function () {
    mySound.stop();
});
```

Can somebody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning it to a variable in the global or outer scope.

```
var myRealSound;
function audio(path2audio){
    var mySound = new buzz.sound ( path2audio, {
        formats: ["mp3"],
        preload: false,
        autoplay: false,
        loop: false,
        volume: 70,
    });

    myRealSound = mySound;

    myRealSound.play();
}


myRealSound.bind('playing', function () {
    myRealSound.stop();
});
```

OR... do the event binding in the same scope as your function.

Comment: In my case, I also had to declare a global variable outside jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){` than it worked.